# Find the dimension of the system with equations and variables

Tags: group-theory

I'm studying dimension of the group now. But I have some trouble with it.

Consider the dimension of 2 by 2 orthogonal group, $O(2)=\{A \in M(2,2,R): AA^T=I\}$

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then by some calculation, we get three equations $a^2+b^2=1 , c^2+d^2=1, ac+bd=0$.

So, can I say that 'there was four free variable, and three equations, now it's dimesion is one although equations are not linear equation'?

Thank you

Comment: Hey. If you feel like your question has been anwsered, please accept the given answer. If not, please explain why and how it can be answered better and/or ask a follow up question, linking it here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
You need to show that your system of equations does not include "repetition".

Suppose your conditions $A \in G \iff \phi(A)=0$, where $\phi : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ (i.e. "there are $p$ condition equations).
In order to be able to conclude that the dimension of $G$ as a Lie group is $n^2 - p$, you need to show that $\phi$ is locally surjective. This translates to a condition on the rank of the differential of $\phi$.

More specifically, your conditions could be rephrased as $\phi(A) = AA^T-I = 0$, which is $n^2$ equations (in your case, n=2). However, only $n(n+1)/2$ of those are "free equations", namely the rank of the differential of $\phi$ is only  $n(n+1)/2$, and the dimension of $O(n)$ is $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you sir. Why those n(n+1)/2 of equations are free equations?, what's the exact definition of free equations?

Comment: 1/ Because the rank of the differential of $\phi$ is $n(n+1)/2$.
2/ A set of free equations is a relationship$\phi(X) = 0$ where the differential of $\phi$ has full rank everywhere. Intuitively, "no equation can be deduced from the others".